# Cómo homologar todas las versiones de proyecto Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, packages, angular12

se me presentó la situación en que algunas cosas no coinciden en sintaxis en mi local en un proyecto Angular al que hice clone y necesito homologar todas las versiones, y no se como cambiar las versiones de algunas dependencias en especifico:
Al correr el comando "ng --version"

Estas son las versiones de mi proyecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y estas son las versiones a como lo debo homologar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto porque me ha dado problemas en el html y en las declaraciones de tipados en los archivos .ts, en el html en cosas como esta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que en el proyecto original no da problemas pero en el mío que clone, sí me está dando este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y en el typescript errores de este tipo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el archivo package.json de ambos:

```
    {
  "name": "",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build-qa": "ng build",
    "build-production": "ng build --configuration production",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.1.0",
    "@angular/animations": "^12.2.12",
    "@angular/cdk": "^12.2.12",
    "@angular/common": "~12.2.12",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.2.12",
    "@angular/core": "~12.2.12",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.2.12",
    "@angular/localize": "^12.2.12",
    "@angular/material": "^12.2.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.2.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.2.12",
    "@angular/router": "~12.2.12",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^6.2.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.3",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.43.3",
    "agm-direction": "^0.8.10",
    "angular-file-saver": "^1.1.3",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.4",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "file-saver": "^1.3.8",
    "ng2-pdf-viewer": "^6.4.1",
    "ngx-captcha": "^10.0.0",
    "ngx-google-places-autocomplete": "^2.0.5",
    "ngx-mask": "7.4.3",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "pdfmake": "^0.2.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.7",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.2.12",
    "@angular/cli": "~12.2.12",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.2.12",
    "@angular/language-service": "~12.2.12",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/jspdf": "^2.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.7",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.3.5"
  }
}
```

Ojalá me puedan apoyar, gracias!!

Comment: Revisa el package.json del proyecto

Comment: Las versiones patch no deberían representar un problema. La única diferencia que veo es que tu estas usando `npm 8.19` contra `npm 6.14`. Pero te instalo todos los paquetes bien. El digito final `xx.xx.patch` es de seguridad ó cambios que no rompen la compatibilidad. Tienes algún error al correr el código?

Comment: Sí, me está dando errores, ya actualicé la pregunta, muchas gracias!

Comment: Ese no es realmente el problema, lo que sucede es que tu versión está utilizando Typescript Strict Mode. 
Desactivalo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57566377/turning-off-strict-mode-in-angular

Comment: Era eso, muchas gracias !!, si gustas ponerlo como respuesta y la marco